# MS Access Combobox row item is not being selected when I click on it

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I've been searching for an answer for 2 days now, here and elsewhere, this is driving me nuts (again).  I have a simple combo box on a simple form.  The drop down populates with the expected list when I click on it, but nothing fires when I click on a row item itself, nothing updates.

Say I have Apples, Oranges, Berry -- I click on Oranges and nothing happens, nothing changes.

- Control Source = "=[tblDivisions]![Division]"
- Row Source = "tblDivisions"
- Row Source Type = Table/query
- Locked = No

I have tried using `Me.DivisionDDL.Requery` without luck and things like cascaded drop-downs.

None of these worked either:

- Private Sub DivisionDDL_Click()
- Private Sub DivisionDDL_OnClick()
- Private Sub DivisionDDL_AfterUpdate()
- and others

How can I get this to work?

```
    Option Compare Database

Private Sub Form2_Load()

Me.DivisionDDL.RowSource = "Select bc_subs.Division FROM _bc_subs"

Me.DivisionDDL = Me.DivisionDDL.ItemData(0)
'DivisionDDL_AfterUpdate

End Sub

Private Sub DivisionDDL_Click()
Me.DivisionDDL.Requery
MsgBox DivisionDDL.List(DivisionDDL.ListIndex)
End Sub
```

Comment: What code are you trying?  Both Click and AfterUpdate should fire.  Have you tried putting a breakpoint in your code?

Comment: [[Looks like code blocks dont work here, so I will edit my above code]]I have went through about 40 different code snippets I've found on line, so it is something stupid.  Some of the code I used is now above here, but it is not the extent of my experimenting with this.

Comment: Do you have any code in the procedures for onclick or afterupdate?

Comment: Best way to figure out if an event is actually firing is to throw a breakpoint in the event.  Once you know they're firing, then you proceed from there with the actions you want to take.

Comment: When you select the combobox control in design view, is there an event assigned in the event property tab? (Specifically, the `Click` event?) Ironically, Access will ignore all your code, if the corresponding line in the event tab is empty.

Comment: Not sure it is relevant, but sometimes Access loses the link between the control and event. Just make sure your AfterUpdate event for the Combobox has the term [Event Procedure] in the properties window. The AfterUpdate event is what you want to use, not OnClick.  Also, as already suggested, put a breakpoint to make sure it is being hit.

Comment: OnClick and AfterUpdate both have [Event Procedure] listed for them

Comment: What do you expect to see happening? As far as I can see in your example, you're setting a rowsource for a dropdown and when you click an item in that dropdown you're performing a requery on that same dropdown. Why should the result be different?
Or to refer to your other example: When you have Apples, Oranges, and Berry and you select Oranges, should your dropdown contain other fruits?
Or am I misreading your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you DanielG - The root form itself has set to "editable - no" but the controls themselves were fine. Why on earth would that be a default setting- idk. I did not think I had to look at the form itself, when dealing strictly with a combo box control, but thank you.

Comment: Nevertheless, a calculated field (control source starts with `=`) is never editable.

Answer (score 0):

> Control Source =  `=[tblDivisions]![Division]`

That's a calculated field, which cannot be edited.

If this should be a bound control, where you edit a table field, use `Division`.

If it is an unbound control, which is used e.g. in a cascading combobox setting, use an empty control source.

Comment: Even using the wizard, it does not work.  I make a Combobox, and use the logical options (Get values from another table --> Select tblDivisions --> Select Division column --> Next/next/next/finish)  This populated the drop down but it too does not allow me to select an option strait from the wizard.

Comment: I don't see a way to create your control source using the combobox wizard. But it doesn't matter, select the appropriate control source from the property window (either a column from the form's record source or empty), and it will work.

Comment: Is the Record Source of the form editable, or maybe set to Snapshot?

Comment: Thank you DanielG - The form itself has set to editable - no.  Why on earth would that be a default setting.  I did not think I had to look at the form itself, when dealing strictly with a combo box control, that is so weird.          Any ideas 'why'?

Comment: That is a little strange, why the default would be Editable = False for the Form. Maybe you used the Record Source Builder at some point (Query Builder), and at a moment in time the underlying Record Source was not editable. Access may have been trying to help, but in the end it caused headaches.